# AOSP 6 Single volume control

Tags: android, build, frameworks, android-source

I'm trying to build AOSP 7 and want to remove all volume controls expect media volume. So volume up\down control only media volume

I found that 8 has config_single_volume in framework core config.xml.

```
<!-- Flag indicating whether all audio streams should be mapped to
         one single stream. If true, all audio streams are mapped to
         STREAM_MUSIC as if it's on TV platform. -->
    <bool name="config_single_volume">false</bool>
```

How to make it on older 7 android version?